# Customize dates in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, date, datepicker, angular5

I would like to customize dates in Angular for my project.

I want to create an algorithm who calculates the working days of my company between 2 dates given by the user.

This period shouldn't count the weekends and holidays which will be given to the app from a file who contains an Array of holiday dates.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I must supouse that your dates are stores as string in the format yyyy-mm-dd (in your array and your fromDate and toDate). To take account of "holidays and weekEnds you can filter your array and count the array. To know the diference of to days you can use new (Date(toDate).getTime()-new Date(fromDate).getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)

Comment: Good plan. What is your question?

Comment: Well I was wondering how can I browse the interval between (Start & End date) day by day
and then : If xx.[i].getDay in [1..5] and not in [Holidays file] {Dayscount++   }

I hope you understand me and I would love to have other ideas from you